# Entity Framework code first connection status checking

Tags: ef-code-first, database-connection

I am trying to produce a little code, that checks, wheather my SQL server is connectable. And: if so, then it should check if the database is existing.
Let me explain it via code.

This is my main-method:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDbContext>());
            Console.WriteLine(CheckIfDatabaseExists("Data Source=127.0.0.1\\SQLEXPRESS2;Initial Catalog=SQLTest;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=3"));
            Console.WriteLine(CheckIfDatabaseExists("Data Source=127.0.0.1\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SQLTest;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=3"));
            Console.WriteLine(CheckIfDatabaseExists("Data Source=127.0.0.1\\SQLEXPRESS2;Initial Catalog=SQLTest;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=3"));
        }
```

As you can imagine: there is an existing database 'SQLTest' on my local SQL server 'SQLEXPRESS'.
But: there is no server like 'SQLEXPRESS2' !

Okay - more code. Here comes my checking method:

```
public static DatabaseExistsStatus CheckIfDatabaseExists(String connString)
        {
          try
            {

                using (var db = new MyDbContext(connString))
                {
                    bool DbExists = db.Database.Exists();
                    if (DbExists)
                    {
                        // database is existing
                        return DatabaseExistsStatus.EXISTING;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // config is working, but database does not exist
                        return DatabaseExistsStatus.NO_DB;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // no working config
                return DatabaseExistsStatus.NO_CONNECTION;
            }
        }

        public enum DatabaseExistsStatus
        {
            EXISTING,
            NO_CONNECTION,
            NO_DB
        }
```

Starting my app brings the following result:

```
NO_CONNECTION
EXISTING 
NO_DB
```

I am confused! I expected "NO_CONNECTION, EXISTING, NO_CONNECTION" .

And that's it!I have no idea what is happening in the background and how to get control.

What is happening there and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

It's a sort of an expected behavior I think (in part at least), as far as I understand (and short of going into reflector)

Take a look at this thorough explanation at how DbContext is initialized, [Code First: Inside DbContext Initialization](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/04/15/code-first-inside-dbcontext-initialization/)

Simplified a bit - `DbContext` does not recreate things for each `new DbContext`. Inside, the EDM (entity data model) and some other things (a 'real' `ObjectContext` instance) is cached for an `AppDomain`.

In this particular case, first call does nothing, it fails locating the server and has no 'viable' alternative - so it simply errors out - and you get 'no connection'.

On the next pass it succeeds and initialized some of the data inside (which is 'global' for the AppDomain - meaning your app in most cases) - the very '`new DbContext`' does pretty much nothing, but on first use, in your case the '`Exists`' it doesn't create the Db but does some initialization (seemingly).

And on the last pass, it tries to open a connection, fails - BUT it already has a valid connection which could be reused from the already initialized data it has.

The only question is why would it 'continue' on the 'failed' connection attempt and reuse the old one (as it's an explicit call), I have no answer to that - but it's what it does it seems (and it's the internal implementation - or a bug?).

Comment: Hey there, thank you for your help. I red the article "Code First: Inside DbContext Initialization" - but unfortunately I am getting no information of how to fix my problem ;) Anyone here who could give me some other tips ?

Answer (score 0):

you can control connection status with this code

```
var db = new MyDbContext(connString));
if (db.Database.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
{
    // do something
}
```